# Cakephp bake error after schema change

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I am trying to regenerate all scaffolding after a DB schema change, and getting exception `SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'db01.address_types' doesn't exist in [/.../vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Database/Schema/Collection.php, line 130]`

`address_types` WAS previously a table, but has been changed to enum named `address_type`, so table is gone and it is even getting the pluralisation wrong! Where is cake/bake getting the old schema from ?

Answer (score 0):

For future reference, the problem was that I had 'backed up' some old tables with a 'z.' prefix, to keep them (just in case), somehow these were still referenced, so once I removed them, those references were gone.  Oops :)

Comment: You need to delete the cache (`tmp/cache/models`) after making changes to the schema.